# Yin-Yang Table Generator

Tags: code-golf, random, binary-matrix

I want an n*n table that is filled with black or white and the following conditions are satisfied in it:

1. All cells of a 2*2 square in this table should not be the same color.
2. All black and white cells must be connected horizontally or vertically.

Acceptable examples:
[image: Yin-Yang table examples]

*Can anyone design a function that takes n as input and generates an acceptable n*n random table?*

- It is not necessary for the output to be an image, we can use symbols such as 0 and 1 in a two-dimensional array to display the result.

Comment: Should the code generate any one such picture? Or one at random? Must all be possible? What about languages without image support?

Comment: I want a code that generate an acceptable random table. It is not necessary for the output to be an image, we can use symbols such as 0 and 1 in a two-dimensional array to display the result.

Comment: @Shahnazi2002 You should make that clear in the post.

Comment: @Shahnazi2002 If you want random output, you will also need to elaborate what range of outputs and what kind of distribution you want.

Comment: @UnrelatedString The distribution should indeed be clarified, since neither of the two existing answers output a random result on every run. But the range of outputs is imo clear, based on the two numbered bullet points: every overlapping 2x2 block should contain at least one of each color; and both all black and all white cells should each (horizontally/vertically) connected form a single 'island'.

Comment: When people here see the word "random", they expect that you want programs that can output one of *multiple tables* at random. If you don't intend that, I suggest to change "random table" to "a table of your choice". If you do, please check out [things to avoid when writing challenges: random without further specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/78410).

Comment: [tag:random] tag means the program may output different grid if you run it multiple times. If you want to say _whatever_ rather than _random_, or say, that "you can output any grid that satisfy the requirement", you should use [tag:open-ended-function] tag here.

Comment: I was just checking back on this.  I want to make sure to say that closure is only intended to be temporary, to stop people from confusedly answering this incorrectly.  Feel free to clarify what you mean and ping me or flag for moderator attention, and I'll open this again.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 45 bytes

```python
lambda n:["1"*n]+[("10"*n)[:n]]*(n-2)+["0"*n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwFET3PcXnr/JbFVN3AU@SBkkx1kidlJCNp49xI53VzOPBbJ/yTLjUJeBW/LwGutJUV/@e755gLGvu4QarWJ9bE2vgXK9wHGWw/EOuPlKmSBGUPZagxgNpLaajli1HFBVlN3gCn14pQv0/myB7Rbr6BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9428/43319)

Anonymous tacit prefix function, returning a matrix of 0s and 1s.

```apl
⊢↑1⍪2↓,⍨⍴2|⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXokdtEw0f9a4yetQ2WedR74pHvVuMah71bv6f9qhtwqPevkddzY961wBFD603Bip91Dc1OMgZSIZ4eAb/TzsEVL/ZDAA)

`⍳` **i**ndices 1…n

`2|` division remainder for those, when divided by 2 (gives `[1,0,1,0,…]`)

`⍴` cyclically reshape into an array of the following dimensions:

`,⍨` the self-concatenation of n, i.e. `[n,n]`

`2↓` drop the first two rows

`1⍪` prepend a row of 1s

`↑` take the following number of rows, padding with all-0 rows:

`⊢` n (lit. the identity function applied to n)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Same output (based on input) on each run:

```
Å1āÉI<.Da)
```

Port of [*@Somebody*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268531/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKvhkcbDnZ42ei6Jmv//WwIA) or [verify the first ten sizes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W8UcnRHmZJnXkFpiZWCkn2lDpeSf2kJjPf/cKvhkcbDnZU2ei6Jmv9tlQKKUktKKnULijLzSlJTFPJhSnW8Du3WObTN/j8A).

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 73 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Random valid output on each run:

```
1ÝIãIãʒ€ü2ü2εøOO4Ö≠}˜P}ʒD_‚ε©˜ƶ®gäΔ2Fø0δ.ø}2Fø€ü3}®*εεÅsyøÅs«à}}}˜Ùg<}P}Ω
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8PBcz8OLgejUpEdNaw7vMQKic1sP7/D3Nzk87VHngtrTcwJq9Yr0zk1xiX/UMOvc1kMrT885tu3QuvTDS85NMXI7vMPg3Ba9wztqQUywCca1h9ZpndsKNKS1uPLwDiB5aPXhBbW1QJMOz0y3qQ34/98YAA) (Slightly modified `ʒ...}Ω` to `.r.Δ...` to speed it up, but unfortunately it'll still time out for \$n\geq4\$.)

**Explanation:**

```python
Å1            # Push a list of the (implicit) input amount of 1s
  ā           # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
   É          # Check for each whether it's odd: [1,0,1,0,1,0,...]
    I<        # Push the input-1
      .D      # Duplicate the [1,0,1,0,1,0,...]-list that many times
        a     # Change the top list to a list of 0s instead with an is_letter check
         )    # Wrap all lists on the stack into a list
              # (after which this matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

Step 1: Create a list of all possible input by input matrices with `0`s and `1`s:

```python
1Ý            # Push pair [0,1]
  Iã          # Take the cartesian power of the input to get all input-sized lists using
              # 0s and 1s
    Iã        # And again, to get all possible matrices
```

Step 2: Filter this list of matrices to keep all where each overlapping 2x2 block contains at least one `1` and at least one `0`:

```python
ʒ             # Filter this list of matrices by:
 €ü2ü2εø      #  Get all overlapping 2x2 blocks:
 €            #   Map over each row:
  ü2          #    Get its overlapping pairs
    ü2        #   Get the overlapping lists of lists of pairs
      ε       #   Map over each:
       ø      #    Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
 OO           #    Sum each inner 2x2 block
   4Ö≠        #    Check for each sum whether it's NOT divisible by 4
              #    (aka it's 1, 2, or 3, and NOT 0 or 4)
      }       #   Close the map
       ˜      #   Flatten this matrix of 2x2 block sum checks
        P     #   Check that all are truthy by taking the product
}             # Close the filter
```

Step 3: Filter it again to keep those where all matrices where both the `1`s and `0`s form a single island:

```python
ʒ             # Filter this list of matrices again:
 D            #  Duplicate this matrix
  _           #  Invert each 0s to 1 and vice-versa in the copy
   ‚          #  Pair the two inverted matrices together
 ε            #  Map over this pair:
  ©           #   Store the current matrix in variable `®` (without popping)
   ˜          #   Flatten it to a single list
    ƶ         #   Multiply each value by its 1-based index
     ®gä      #   Convert it back to a matrix of size `®`
  Δ           #   Loop until the result no longer changes to flood-fill:
   2Fø0δ.ø}   #    Add a border of 0s around the matrix:
   2F     }   #     Loop 2 times:
     ø        #     Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       δ      #     Map over each row:
      0 .ø    #      Add a leading/trailing 0
   2Fø€ü3}    #    Convert it into overlapping 3x3 blocks: 
   2F    }    #     Loop 2 times again:
     ø        #      Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
      €       #      Map over each inner list:
       ü3     #       Convert it to a list of overlapping triplets
   ®*         #    Multiply each 3x3 block by the value in matrix `®`
              #    (so the 0s remain 0s)
   εεÅsyøÅs«à #    Get the largest value from the horizontal/vertical cross of each
              #    3x3 block:
   εε         #     Nested map over each 3x3 block:
     Ås       #       Pop and push its middle row
       y      #       Push the 3x3 block again
        ø     #       Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
         Ås   #       Pop and push its middle rows as well (the middle column)
           «  #       Merge the middle row and column together to a single list
            à #       Pop and push its maximum
   }}         #     Close the nested maps
  }           #   Close the changes-loop
   ˜          #   Flatten the flood-filled matrix
    Ù         #   Uniquify this list
     g<       #   Pop and push its length-1
              #   (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, so this checks if two islands remain)
 }            #  Close the map
  P           #  Check that both are truthy, for the regular and inverted matrix
}             # Close the filter
 Ω            # Pop and push a random matrix from this filtered list
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```